# python run binary application in memory and return output

Tags: python

I want protect my commercial application with `hwid protection`, I have this demidecode : http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm return UUID of computer where run, the problem is need include this in python code ==> run in memory ==> return output and close, is possible this in python ?
or exist another method to get this UUID of computer ?

actual code :

```
subprocess.Popen('dmidecode.exe -s system-uuid'.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `check_output` to get the output of the shell command:

```
import subprocess    
out = subprocess.check_output('dmidecode.exe -s system-uuid').decode('utf-8').strip()    
print('system uuid:', out)
# system uuid: 6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8
```

Comment: i need include in python code, not normal run

Comment: @selfmarket.net This runs in a python script. I don't understand your goal.